# Extract ActionScript from SWF using C#

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, adobe, extract

Is there a way using C# to extract the ActionScript from a .SWF file? I know it can be done as there are third party command line tools that will do it, but I need to do it programmatically using C#. I'm open to using third party libraries (free or paid) as long as they are from reliable vendors, but I haven't been able to find any .NET libraries that will do it, just command line or Windows programs so far.

**EDIT**: Are there any options other than SWFTools? I'm a little hesitant to include unmanaged code in my application.

Comment: Could you post links to the command-line tools you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library : http://swf.codeplex.com/ is a .net library for parsing SWF content. Though it does not have code for extracting AS3 / AS2 code.

SWFTools (http://www.swftools.org/) library has code for extracting AS code from SWF.

I would use C/C++ code from SWFTools for handling SWF and link it with rest of C# project.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these out. Looking at the link (swf.codeplex.com), in the description it mentions: Includes Actionscript support (read and write, at the bytecode level). I'm not very familiar with Flash/Actionscript (just got tasked with this out of nowhere). Does that mean it can read older Actionscript but not AS3 or AS2, specifically?

Comment: That code would fail with AS3, will have to use SWFTools for that.